# Can we run utilities (sewer) to a new building from an existing house, or do we need parallel external hookups?

Tags: electrical, water, sewer, new-home

We're looking into building a new "tiny home" (or at least fairly small) as an auxiliary dwelling unit on the same lot as our existing home.
One of the major concerns is how we'll hook up sewer, water, and electric. Running a new sewer line from the street around our house to the back yard would be particularly difficult.

Ideally I would daisy chain the buildings: The new sewer line would run from the new building into our existing basement where it would join the existing sewer line; cold water would be handled similarly. (Electrical could be just another circuit on our breaker, or whatever, it's less likely to block the project.) My first idea is to bury a culvert between the two basements <sub>(assuming the new building has a basement)</sub>, and run all the utilities through it next to each other, but burring them separately could also be ok.

What's the normal way to approach this situation? Is the above problematic? I'm in the north of the U.S., does this sound reasonable from a code-enforcement perspective?

<sub>I want it to be stand-alone construction, A) to avoid immediately dealing with the janky-ness of the existing 100+yo building, B) more specifically because there's lead paint under our siding that we don't want to disturb yet, and C) so that future major renovations/reconstructions of the existing building can have minimal impact on the auxiliary one. Ultimately I'd like the structures to be connected by a shared covered porch, to which end the new building will be 6-12' from the existing one, but IDK when we'll get around to that.</sub>

Comment: It will depend on where you are exactly(don't say on here).  It is up to your local town/city/county if allowed or not.

Comment: If lucky, your locality will have the regulations/requirements listed on their website.  It should only be the sewer that might give trouble.  We kind of forgot to mention the extra bathroom when we did it in the olden days, but we had septic and well.  Times have changed and they seem more picky these days.

Comment: If your local code lumps together detached ADUs and under-the-same-roof ADUs, then I suspect that you're in luck. The ADU is a zoning thing, so regulations will vary widely between different jurisdictions. My jurisdiction publishes the stuff online, although I've mapped the information back to city council resolutions with all of that "whereas" language to (unsuccessfully) resolve ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks both of you! It doesn't sound like either of you anticipate engineering problems, so it's just a legal question. I'll figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go halfway between your two extremes. Run a new sewer line from *the front yard* around to the new ADU structure. More specifically, find an existing clean-out tap in the sewer lateral in the front yard and insert a wye fitting to connect your new branch at that point.

Yes it's more distance compared to entering the house from the rear. But it keeps all the excavation outdoors where it can be done with machinery, and it avoids routing the effluent from one building into another. That just seems like a Good Idea in case any sort of obstruction might develop inside the existing house plumbing.